# How to findByAll with a Domain hasMany member?

Tags: search, grails, grails-orm

I have:

```
static hasMany = [
    services:String,
    tags:String
]
```

I need to search the database for services.

This is the JSON for services

```
 "services":["tid.2","tid.3"]
```

If services was a String (service) and not a hasMany String then tbis works

```
def inUse = ServiceTemplate.findAllByName(serviceTemplateInstance.service).size() > 1
```

How can I do this with services?

I've tried

```
            def c = ServiceTemplate.createCriteria()
            def results = c.list { eq('services', 'tid.2') }
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HQL instead. For example:

```
ServiceTemplate.findAll("from ServiceTemplate st where :service in elements(st.services)", [service:'a'])
```